# How can I use the return value from a query in the other query?

Tags: sql, transactions

This is my first query:

```
Select a1,count(*) as b1 from btable
```

This is my second query:

```
Select a1,a2,a3,.., from atable inner join btable b on a1=b.a1
```

*I mean, in the first query, if b1 gets the value for a1, I want b1 corresponding to the same a1 to get that value in the second query. If there is no corresponding value b1 = 0.*

**example;first query result : if a1=1 and b1=2 ,a1=100 and b1=8....
second query result:a1=1 b1=2,a1=30 b1=0 ,a1=100 b1=8,a1=22 b1=0**

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let me agree with Manash Hazaika and say that your first query MAY not be correct.  Ignoring that, if you want to have the results of the first query accessible to the second query, you may consider using a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) as follows:

```
;with subQuery as
(
   Select a1,count(*) as b1 from btable
)
Select a1,a2,a3,.., from atable inner join subQuery b on a1=b.a1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got your question correctly but the first query seems to be using an aggregate function (count) which should be accompanied by a `group by` clause. If you have to use a `group by` clause, then the b1 values will be 1 for all the rows for each a1

Example:

```
Select a1,count(*) as b1
from btable
group by a1
```

For the 2nd query, you don't really have to use a join; you can achieve that using a simple `where` condition

Example:

```
Select a.a1,a.a2,a.a3,..,
from atable a,btable b
where a.a1=b.a1
```